# Navbar not full width - No Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm intentionally not using Bootstrap. I have a problem that Should be an easy fix but I can't seem to get it right. All I need is my Navbar to fit the top of the browser, right now it stops short of the edges.

VIEW:

```
    <div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to 'Subscribers', subscribers_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_subscriber_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Check In', subscribers_search_path %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .nav {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

NAVBAR:

[image]

if you look close you can see that the bar doesn't reach the corners of the screen. Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: The body element usually has a default padding value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add:

```
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;  
}
```